# Merge all excel sheets via VBA script and then delete remaining sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have got one Excel file with 20 sheets that I want to merge into one.

**Example structure of all sheets**

```
| 1 | https://originalni-tonery.heureka.cz/hp-f6v25ae-originalni/               | 151554 |
| 2 | https://originalni-tonery.heureka.cz/hp-f6v24ae-originalni/               | 151555 |
| 3 | https://originalni-tonery.heureka.cz/canon-pg-545-plus-cl-546-originalni/ | 90737  |
```

**I have been thinking about solution with loop:**

1. Get number of all sheets
2. Start with last one
3. Copy all its content
4. Paste it to first sheet after all data
5. Delete last sheet
6. Go to Step 2 or end when you reach Sheet 1

**Here is what I made so far:**

```
Dim actualsheet As integer
actualsheet = Worksheets.Count
Do While actualsheet < 1
   'Selects last sheet 
   sheets(actualsheet).activate

   'Missing code
        'Select everything from this Sheet
        'Paste it to Sheet 1
        'Delete last Sheet

   'Change actual Sheet
   actualsheet = actualsheet - 1
Loop
```

Thank you and have a nice day! :)

Comment: here's a [quick google search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=Merge+all+excel+sheets+via+VBA&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) and here's its [first link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1184-excel-merge-multiple-worksheets-into-one.html). in no more then 10 seconds